# scroll tableview to top while adding items

Tags: iphone

I have a table view . I added items to the tableview on loading itself at a particular interval. I need to move the contents on top while adding so that i can view recently added items.Any help

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add to the top of your data, you know the one you use to populate the cells, and call -reload on your table to display the change.

If you are using a mutable array, use insertObject:atIndex: at index 0 instead of using addObject: